# Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address

Tags: linux, c, драйвер, kernel, paging

Пытаюсь заставить работать +- новый драйвер на старом кернеле (3.4.113)...всё вроде шло хорошо до момента проверки инжекта пакетов...после инжекта кернел ложится...вот кусочек лога

```
[   66.546989] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 00010031
[   66.547267] pgd = c0004000
[   66.547383] [00010031] *pgd=00000000
[   66.547653] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
[   66.547870] Modules linked in:
[   66.548096] CPU: 0    Not tainted  (3.4.113-gf50fa015c89-dirty #12)
[   66.548310] PC is at rtl8xxxu_tx+0x14/0x514
[   66.548439] LR is at __ieee80211_tx+0x208/0x264
[   66.548473] type=1325 audit(1637116075.966:111): table=filter family=2 entries=138
[   66.548514] type=1320 audit(1637116075.966:111):
[   66.548894] pc : [<c0502740>]    lr : [<c0a43d0c>]    psr: 60000013
[   66.548899] sp : e6b89e20  ip : c050272c  fp : 00000000
[   66.549232] r10: e4650340  r9 : e4650340  r8 : e6b89eb0
[   66.549448] r7 : 00000000  r6 : e5801968  r5 : e4651080  r4 : 00010001
[   66.549571] r3 : 00000000  r2 : 00010001  r1 : e1819780  r0 : e4650340
[   66.549789] Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment kernel
[   66.550000] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 2330806a  DAC: 00000015
```

И трейс

```
[   65.418637] [<c0502740>] (rtl8xxxu_tx+0x14/0x514) from [<c0a43d0c>] (__ieee80211_tx+0x208/0x264)
[   65.418767] [<c0a43d0c>] (__ieee80211_tx+0x208/0x264) from [<c0a450c4>] (ieee80211_tx+0xac/0xc0)
[   65.418979] [<c0a450c4>] (ieee80211_tx+0xac/0xc0) from [<c0a4585c>] (ieee80211_xmit+0x84/0x8c)
[   65.419193] [<c0a4585c>] (ieee80211_xmit+0x84/0x8c) from [<c0a46574>] (ieee80211_tx_skb_tid+0x3c/0x48)
[   65.419401] [<c0a46574>] (ieee80211_tx_skb_tid+0x3c/0x48) from [<c0a32d70>] (ieee80211_scan_work+0x368/0x524)
[   65.419628] [<c0a32d70>] (ieee80211_scan_work+0x368/0x524) from [<c01a56d8>] (process_one_work+0x26c/0x3f4)
[   65.419845] [<c01a56d8>] (process_one_work+0x26c/0x3f4) from [<c01a5a20>] (worker_thread+0x194/0x2c4)
[   65.419976] [<c01a5a20>] (worker_thread+0x194/0x2c4) from [<c01aa164>] (kthread+0x80/0x8c)
[   65.420196] [<c01aa164>] (kthread+0x80/0x8c) from [<c0105fc0>] (kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8)
[   65.420410] Code: e24dd02c e590502c e1a04002 e1a0a000 (e5923030)
```

После пробива адреса через addr2line он указал на [rtl8xxxu_core.c:5041](https://github.com/Darkar25/realtek_rtwifi/blob/master/rtl8xxxu_core.c#L5041)

```
struct ieee80211_vif *vif = tx_info->control.vif;
```

После просмотра кода структуры [ieee80211_tx_info](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.4.113/source/include/net/mac80211.h#L557) увидел довольно занимательный комментарий говорящий о том, что указатель tx_info->control.vif может быть NULL для инжектированных пакетов...это как раз таки мой случай...драйвер крашит при инжекте пакетов...

Проверял несколько раз, в разное время, в разных режимах беспроводного адаптера...результат всегда один и тот-же: ничего не крашит кроме этого драйвера, только в этом месте и нигде больше...

В интернете говорят что моя ошибка может возникать из-за использования пустых NULL указателей или из-за аппаратных ошибок памяти...я надеюсь что с памятью у меня в порядке поэтому пока что рассматриваю только теорию с указателями...однако я могу ошибаться и вся эта шелуха с указателями тут совсем не при чём...

UPD:В ходе обсуждения в комментариях мы пришли к выводу что косячный именно я а не драйвер который я форкнул так как на актуальном ядре он работает исправно а на 3.4 крашит...

UPD2:При добавлении проверки на NULL

```
if(tx_info == NULL) goto error;
```

после строки [rtl8xxxu_core.c:5036](https://github.com/Darkar25/realtek_rtwifi/blob/master/rtl8xxxu_core.c#L5036)

```
struct ieee80211_tx_info *tx_info = IEEE80211_SKB_CB(skb);
```

кернел крашиться не перестал но начал жаловаться на [rtl8xxxu_core.c:5035](https://github.com/Darkar25/realtek_rtwifi/blob/master/rtl8xxxu_core.c#L5035)

```
struct ieee80211_hdr *hdr = (struct ieee80211_hdr *)skb->data;
```

Comment: от того что vif NULL эта строка ничего ломать не может. NULL переменной присваивать можно. она может приводить к такой ошибке только если tx_info содержит NULL, а он судя по коду берется из sk_buff.cb так что смотрите что у вас в cb.

Comment: @Mike прошелся по сурцам некоторых подобных драйверов...нигде не делается никаких дополнительных проверок после IEEE80211_SKB_CB(skb), сразу идёт запись в указатель с последующим обращением к нему...значит по логике sk_buff.cb не бывает NULL...

Comment: по этому поводу лучше попробовать связаться с тем, кто бекпортировал драйвер... вряд ли кто-то тут с ходу что-то придумает...

Comment: @Fat-Zer это мой репозиторий и я его бэкпортировал :D

Comment: мда... ситуация «если не удалось решить проблему, обратитесь к системному администратору» на спидах =))

Comment: Я бы ещё проверил, если есть возможность, не происходит ли тоже самое в том модуле с которого ты форкнул на свежем ядре...

Comment: @Fat-Zer идея хорошая...попробую проверить...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131531/discussion-between---and-fat-zer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче я разобрался...во время компиляции была пачка подобных варнингов

```
/home/kali/matissewifi_kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu_core.c: At top level:
/home/kali/matissewifi_kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu_core.c:6078:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
  .tx = rtl8xxxu_tx,
  ^
```

я им сначала значения не придал...а потом решил узнать что же это такое...оказалось что это довольно важная штука, функции объявленные мной и функции требуемые в ieee80211_ops отличались...впринципе логично...поменял их, пересобрал драйвер и теперь всё идеально...

вывод: во время разработки драйверов игнорить предупреждения не нужно, они могут вам сильно попортить нервы...это вам не C# какой-нибудь или python, тут нужно прислушиваться ко всем предупреждениям...